# Using CSS content attribute vs JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm creating input that shows different notes based on content. First, I tried using content attribute of CSS, but it only works for :before and :after selectors.

So, I created another div element, using :before on it to display the note text. Should I switch to using JavaScript to do this?

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4gm6pbw/1/)

*HTML*:

```
<div class="link-input-container">
  <input class="link-input" placeholder="Zalijepi link ovdje..." type="text" class="url_input" name="url_input">
</div>
<div class="link-note no-input">
  <div class="link-note-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*:

```
.link-input-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.link-input-container::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: transparent url('data:image/png;base64,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') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(100%);
}

.link-input-container.valid::after {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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')
}

.link-input {
  font-family: Courier New;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.link-input-container.valid .link-input {
  color: green;
}

.link-input-container:not(valid) .link-input {
  color: red;
}

.link-note {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.link-note.no-input {
  color: rgb(193, 162, 0);
}

.link-note.no-input .link-note-content:before {
  content: "*Link nije unesen";
}

.link-note.valid {
  color: green;
}

.link-note.valid .link-note-content:before {
  content: "*Stisni enter da dodas ovaj link";
}

.link-note.invalid {
  color: red;
}

.link-note.invalid .link-note-content:before {
  content: "*Link nije ispravan";
}
```

*JS*:

```
function toggleClass(elem, class_name, class_on) {
  if (class_on) {
    elem.classList.add(class_name);
  } else {
    elem.classList.remove(class_name);
  }
}

function switchClass(elem, class_list, on_class) {
  for (var i = 0; i < class_list.length; i++) {
    elem.classList.remove(class_list[i]);
  }
  elem.classList.add(on_class);
}

function LinkInput() {
  LinkInput = null;

  var self = {
    container_elem: null,
    input_elem: null,
    note_elem: null,

    init: () => {
      var container_elem = self.container_elem = document.querySelector(
        '.link-input-container'
      );

      var input_elem = self.input_elem = document.querySelector(
        '.link-input'
      );
      input_elem.size = 23;

      var note_elem = self.note_elem = document.querySelector(
        '.link-note'
      );

      input_elem.addEventListener('input', (ev) => {
        var new_val = input_elem.value;

        var new_size = new_val.length;
        input_elem.size = Math.max(new_size + 2, 23);

        if (new_val.length > 5) {
          switchClass(note_elem, [
            "no-input", "invalid", "valid"
          ], "valid");

          toggleClass(container_elem, "valid", true);
        } else {
          if (new_val === "") {
            switchClass(note_elem, [
              "no-input", "invalid", "valid"
            ], "no-input");
          } else {
            switchClass(note_elem, [
              "no-input", "invalid", "valid"
            ], "invalid");
          }

          toggleClass(container_elem, "valid", false);
        }
      });

      input_elem.addEventListener('keyup', (ev) => {
        if (ev.keyCode == 13) {
          input_elem.value = "";
          input_elem.blur();

          // Submit

          return false;
        }
      });
    },
  };

  self.init();
  return self;
}

var link_input = LinkInput();
```

Comment: One problem of `content` is that the text is not selectable

Comment: Thanks. I actually like that in this case.

Comment: What is the specific problem and question?

Comment: Is it good practice to use CSS in such cases or is it better to use Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you. I think notifications should be driven by javascript as it's not part of the site at the moment it loads. Im thinking some SEO here, not that the search engines should save notifications like that anyways. Well that's my opinion :)

Cheers!